# Difference between (factor|group) and (1|factor:group) specifications in lme4

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

I have a repeated measures from clusters, over several years, and I expect the cluster effect to vary each year.  Year is coded as a factor, with '1' as reference level.
I have tried the following:

```
mod1 <- lmer(y ~ x + year + (year|cluster))
```

and

```
mod2 <- lmer(y ~ x + year + (1|cluster:year))
```

My first example specifies the following random effects:

```
ranef(mod1)
$cluster
    (Intercept)  year2         year3        year4         year5
AA   0.03721015  0.0573160920 -0.114709171  0.1588302187  0.125329740
AB  -0.12958994 -0.0458997003  0.216455596  0.2345170893  0.248950509
AC  -5.10692972 -0.1311546328  1.130347798  2.5215580167  5.070106525
AD   0.10087455 -0.2677088515 -0.345583355 -0.2442831982 -0.257074662
....
```

Second one specifies:

```
ranef(mod2)
$`cluster:year`
              (Intercept)
AA:year2  0.0838186244
AA:year3 -0.1197284361
AA:year4  0.1944488619
AA:year5  0.1562090690
```

I assumed they would be equivalent, given year is a factor, but I must not understand the random effect specification of `lme4` well enough. Can anyone help me understand the difference between the two parameterizations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At first sight, there are two main differences:

1. mod1 is a **random intercept** and **random slope** model while mod2 is a random intercept model (without random slope): `(year|cluster)` implicitly includes the intercept and thus expands to `(1 + year|cluster)`. In this case you assume a different baseline for each cluster and allow the clusters to vary with respect to the year effect.
2. mod2 includes an **interaction**, mod1 doesn't: As mod2 only includes a random intercept for the cluster*year interaction you get the estimates for every unique combination of the factor levels (i.e. AA:year2, AA:year3, ...)

Note that mod1 estimates $k$ variances and $k(k-1)/2$ correlations for the $k$ random effects per cluster. If you constrain the cluster-related variances to be equal and all the correlations also to be equal (this is called *compound symmetry*), you get a model with many fewer (only two) variance/covariance parameters:

```
mod3 <- lmer(y ~ x + year + (1|cluster) + (1|year:cluster))
```

(*note the similarity/difference compared to mod2*) which can be useful when there is not enough information in the data to estimate mod1.
For more on this see [this](http://www.rpubs.com/Reinhold/22193) excellent post by Reinhold Kliegl and also my follow-up question: [Equivalence of (0 + factor|group) and (1|group) + (1|group:factor) random effect specifications in case of compound symmetry](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304374/).

So mod3 can be seen as a restricted version of mod1. Your mod2 is restricted even further, but this one-parameter parametrization is arguably less realistic.

Comment: Thanks @statmars, that makes it clearer.  I'd confused the 'every unique combination' element with each intercept having 5 variations.  I'd be warned not to refer to it as a slope, when using a factor, as it's not continuous.  Would you agree?  May I suggest a small edit to 2.?  I think you mean _'mod2 includes an **interaction**, mod1 doesn't...'_

Comment: You are right, it's 'mod1 doesn't'! Note my edit (mod3): maybe you just forgot the `(1|cluster)` term. Mod3 can be an option given the constraints I mentioned.

Comment: +1. Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304374

Comment: (+1) You probably meant that the correlations should be constrained to be equal, not zero. I made this edit, make sure that you agree. I also inserted a link to your own Q about compound symmetry, it looks directly relevant.

Comment: @amoeba I meant that `mod3` estimates 0 correlation parameters and yes, you are right, thus constrains the cluster-related correlations to be equal. Thanks for linking to my Q.