# For what types of research designs should (Days|Subject) vs. (1|Days:Subject) random effect specification be used?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am learning generalized linear mixed effects model, and today I realized that there are two ways to set random slope in `lmer()`, when dealing with data where same subjects are repeatedly measured.

```
fit1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
fit2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Days:Subject), sleepstudy)
```

Looking at the results, it seems like `lmer()` doing different things. How each command differs from each other, and which should I use and when?

**Update:** Thanks to Matteo Lisi's answer and to the earlier post [Difference between (factor|group) and (1|factor:group) specifications in lme4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302951), I now understand the mechanism that the `lme4` package is doing. However, I am still having difficulty understanding WHEN should I use WHICH. I would appreciate if you could explain for what types of research designs I should use which syntax.

1. Is that something I can choose based on AIC? Or, I should choose the syntax based on the design of the research?
2. Could you provide examples of research designs?

Comment: Near duplicates: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302951/ https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304374

Comment: I still think this is a duplicate (cc @gung). The accepted answer in the https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302951 provides some guidance as to when to use which model and links to a further resource discussing this in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out and letting me know the similar answers, @amoeba. Because I am a novice R user and just have learned only the practical aspects of statistics: what to do for which type of analyses without understanding the statistical knowledge deeply. So, what's written in the duplicate makes sense, but, I cannot make up with specific examples of research designs by myself. I would like to revise my question to clarify my intention, if this web site is open for people who is looking for practical suggestions.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you still don't understand here. The linked answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/302969/28666 provides guidance and a link for further reading. These two random effect specifications are suitable for THE SAME research design. But one model is more complicated than another. Re AIC, MatteoLisi uses it in his answer here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @amoeba. I've checked the link. I may have missed the part it stated that both syntaxes are suited for the same research design. Since a random slope + random intercept model and random slope for an _interaction_ of `Days` and `Subject` seem quite different to me, I thought there should be different types of research designs that are more suited to one of the two syntaxes.

Comment: I thought @MatteoLisi did not specifically suggest to use AIC, but just stated that we can see the difference of the models described by AIC and BIC. But, if that was what he meant, sorry for keeping this already answered question.

Comment: Let me try to elaborate (I have also made some edits to the answer in the linked thread; maybe they will help). You should distinguish a situation where `Days` is continuous vs. categorical. If it's continuous then the models are not really comparable, because fit2 treats it as categorical. But imagine `Days` were categorical. Then the main point is that fit2 is a restricted version of fit1. If you add (1|Days) to the model, then it's fit1 restricted to "compound symmetry". Whether you want to use a full model or a restricted model, depends primarily on the amount of data you have.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating your comments and editing the previous post! That's exactly what I was looking for. Especially because I was treats some factors (like `Days`) as a categorical variable and a continuous variable while selecting models, I am very happy to learn about the difference from you. Model selection is quite difficult since sometimes we can just use AIC (or BIC) to select models, but sometimes we cannot. Thank you again for your comments and being patient with my questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `fit2` does not really fit a random slope. Instead, it sets a random intercept for each combination of `Days` and `Subject`. This implies that for the computation of the random effects `fit2` treats `Days` as a categorical rather than continuous variable.

You can check the difference by comparing the output of `ranef(fit1)` and `ranef(fit2)`. For this example the correct model is clearly `fit1`, you can see it also by comparing the AIC or BIC of the two models.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear answer! Could you explain more on when I should use `fit1` then?

Comment: More generally, only categorical variables should be put to the right of the `|` symbol in the formula: these indicate the "observational units" (subjects, etc.) according to which the random effects are grouped. Here `fit1` assume that the probability of observing a reaction time longer than the median may depend linearly on the continuous variable `Days` and that this effect can be decomposed in a fixed effect common to all subjects, and in subject-specific random variations. `fit1`formula tells R explicitly to take into account these random variations and estimate their variance.

Comment: So if you want to estimate an effect which may have random fluctuations conditional to the "observational units" on which it is measured, you should use `fit1` format.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand clearly when I should use `fit1`. And I can select the model based on AIC, as well! I am now wondering, so, when `fit2` would be used if `fit1` include random slope and potentially explain the variance better. Would you mind teaching me for type of research design I should use `fit2`?

Comment: that type of formula should be used when you have 2 grouping factors, e.g. `g1` and `g2`, with `g2` nested within `g1`. In that case it makes sense to use a random structure such as `(1 | g1) + (1 | g1:g2)`. To learn more about that I suggest you to read [this article](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v067i01) (see in particular their Table 2 and related information in the main text).

Comment: Thank you very much, Matteo Lisi. So, I can specify the nested factors! I will read the article shortly. Thank you again.

Comment: @user8460166 If you think that Matteo answered your question consider accepting his answer. This is also positive feedback to the person who spent her/his time reading your question and comes up with an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @Stefan. I accepted the answer. :)