# Difference between `fix1 + (1|cluster1)` and `fix1 + (1|fix1:cluster1)` when specifying random intercept using lme4 in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I see sometimes people using two different ways to specify the random effects when conducting multilevel modelling with `lme4` in R.

```
model1 <- lmer(fix1 + (1|cluster1), data = dat)
model2 <- lmer(fix1 + (1|fix1:cluster1), data = dat)
```

Judged by my limited knowledge of multilevel modelling, people seems to use the these two formulas for very similar research designs (e.g., `fix1` is nested within `cluster1`).

Could you explain if these are doing the same thing? Are there any times that I should use one over the other?

Thank you.

---

**Added:**
Thank you for the references, @Stefan.
I think the following explanation in the website (http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-specification) is indicating that both of the above mentioned commands (i.e., `model1` and `model2`) are technically the same.

> site+(1|site:block)
>
> fixed effect of sites plus random variation in intercept among blocks within sites

Based on this, I would like to ask again, if there are any times that I should use one over the other? Or, do the both commands work exactly same all the time? Thank you.

Comment: See here: http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-specification and here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18428/formula-symbols-for-mixed-model-using-lme4 for model specification in `lme4`.

Comment: Thank you for the references, @Stefan. I had made some mistake in the formulas above. I revised it.

Comment: This is a question about R syntax, not statistics per se, and so seems to me to be [off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this stack exchange (but potentially on-topic at Stack Overflow).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between (factor|group) and (1|factor:group) specifications in lme4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302951/difference-between-factorgroup-and-1factorgroup-specifications-in-lme4)

Comment: @Jake That's a reasonable opinion, but I have reversed the migration to SO because the nature of the answer is statistical, even though extensive code is involved in the examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `model1` and `model2` are not the same. `model1` accounts for random variation within `cluster1`, where as `model2` accounts for random variation among `cluster1` within `fix1`. Here's another link to a different post on this site: [Have I correctly specified my model in lmer?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70556/have-i-correctly-specified-my-model-in-lmer)

But let's have quick example to illustrate that. Then you'll see that the estimated standard deviations for the random terms will be different. Also have a look at the line where it says `Number of obs:` and `groups:`. This will indicate that there are differences in the grouping structure as well.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(FIXED=rep(c("A","B","C"), each=12),
                 RANDOM=rep(c("W","X","Y","Z"), each=3),
                 Y=runif(36,1,10))

head(df)
#  FIXED RANDOM        Y
#1     A      W 3.588198
#2     A      W 8.094746
#3     A      W 4.680792
#4     A      X 8.947157
#5     A      X 9.464206
#6     A      X 1.410008

require(lme4)
summary(lmer(Y ~ FIXED + (1|RANDOM), df))
# ...
#    Random effects:
# Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
# RANDOM   (Intercept) 0.4556   0.675   
# Residual             7.1980   2.683   
#Number of obs: 36, groups:  RANDOM, 4

#Fixed effects:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value
#(Intercept)   6.3945     0.8448   7.569
#FIXEDB       -0.1140     1.0953  -0.104
#FIXEDC       -0.3000     1.0953  -0.274
# ...

summary(lmer(Y ~ FIXED + (1|FIXED:RANDOM), df))
# ...
#    Random effects:
# Groups       Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
# FIXED:RANDOM (Intercept) 7.887e-14 2.808e-07
# Residual                 7.571e+00 2.752e+00
#Number of obs: 36, groups:  FIXED:RANDOM, 12

#Fixed effects:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value
#(Intercept)   6.3945     0.7943   8.051
#FIXEDB       -0.1140     1.1233  -0.101
#FIXEDC       -0.3000     1.1233  -0.267
# ...
```

Notice the difference in the standard deviation for the random effects but also the difference in the standard error for the fixed effects!

Now if I added another variable that combines `RANDOM` and `FIXED`, such as

```
df$RANDOM2 <- paste(df$FIXED, df$RANDOM, sep="_")

head(df)
#  FIXED RANDOM        Y RANDOM2
#1     A      W 3.588198     A_W
#2     A      W 8.094746     A_W
#3     A      W 4.680792     A_W
#4     A      X 8.947157     A_X
#5     A      X 9.464206     A_X
#6     A      X 1.410008     A_X
```

and then run

```
summary(lmer(Y ~ FIXED + (1|RANDOM2), df))
# ...
#    Random effects:
# Groups       Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
# FIXED:RANDOM (Intercept) 7.887e-14 2.808e-07
# Residual                 7.571e+00 2.752e+00
#Number of obs: 36, groups:  FIXED:RANDOM, 12

#Fixed effects:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value
#(Intercept)   6.3945     0.7943   8.051
#FIXEDB       -0.1140     1.1233  -0.101
#FIXEDC       -0.3000     1.1233  -0.267
# ...
```

you can see that the output is the same as the output above using random term `+(1|FIXED:RANDOM)`. Why is that? Because `RANDOM` is **implicitly** nested in `FIXED` whereas `RANDOM2` is **explicitly** nested. So the syntax of your random factors depends on the way you setup your data table. I hope this example made the distinction between `+(1|RANDOM)` and `+(1|FIXED:RANDOM)` more clear.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Stefan. I understand the difference completely. I really appreciated that you demonstrated the difference using actual codes. If you would not mind, would it be possible for you to provide some examples of research designs when a `random effect` is nested in a `fixed effect`? This may sound like I am asking an obvious thing, but since I just started learning multilevel modelling, I would like to get an idea of how I can relate these difference codes to actual research designs. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Glad you understood the difference. The research designs you are looking for are called nested designs. Just grab a text book or ask Google for nested design and mixed effects models. There is a lot of information freely available for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Stefan. I will look for examples by starting googling with 'nested designs' then. Thank you again, and I hope you have a great day!