# Repeated measures design and covariate using nlme & lme4

Tags: lme4-nlme

I conducted a full 3x2x2 (`W1`,`W2`,`W3`) within design with every participant experiencing the same 12 conditions. Within each condition, there were several measurements of my outcome variable(`outcome`). Additionally, I want to include a covariate (`covariate`) in my model that was measured as on the same level as my outcome, i.e. several times within each condition.

I set up the model using `nlme`(following Field, Miles, & Field, 2012; chapter 13):

```
Model_lme <-lme(outcome ~ W1 + W2 + W3 + W1:W2 + W1:W3 + W2:W3 + W1:W2:W3 + covariate , 
random = ~covariate|Subject/W1/W2/W3, data = data,control = list(opt = "optim"), method = "ML")
```

And using `lme4`

```
Model_lme4 <- lmer(outcome ~ W1*W2*W3 + covariate +  (1 + covariate|Subject/W1:W2:W3), 
data=data, REML=FALSE)
```

I would be very grateful if someone could answer the following questions:

1) Are these model really equivalent? I'm not sure about the `Lme4` approach right now.

2) When comparing the models without the `covariate`, I find a significant effect of `W2`. After introducing the `covariate`, this main effect is no longer present. Is it then fine to state that the main effect of `W2` was explained by the significant `covariate`?

3) Finally, I am also not sure how to report my model. As I understand, the models describe my data as follows: `W1`, `W2`, and `W3` are nested within participants. These factors have random intercepts (meaning that there is an intercept for each condition within each participant), but no random slopes. The `covariate` is a factor with random intercept and slope.
Is that the way how to describe in a paper? It rather seems like papers only state whether something was handled a fixed or random effect ([e.g. Jainta, Blythe, Nikolova, Jones,& Liversedge, 2015, p. 121](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0042698915001078))

I know these are many questions, but currently I am still really puzzled about mixed models, even though I read and try to understand every literature I can get regarding this topic.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Your W1,W2,W3 are *not* "nested within participants. To say this will be incorrect and misleading. You have a repeated measures design, but subjects are crossed with W1/2/3. Nothing is nested here. The so called "maximal" model would have `(W1*W2*W3 + covariate | Subject)` random term. You can try but this is a lot of random effects to fit, and you might not have enough data to fit this reliably. So you can simplify, e.g. `(W1 + W2 + W3 + covariate | Subject)`, or with `||`. What you have is an even further simplification `(1 + covariate | Subject) + (1 + covariate | Subject:W1:W2:W3)`.

Comment: This last simplification assumes so called "compound symmetry". See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304374/ https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302951 and further linked threads.

Comment: Thanks @amoeba for the very useful clarification and linked threads. As i feel not very confident with the conduction and interpretation of mixed models, I want to build up a model as close to the approach of a repeated measures ANOVA, but with the integrated covariate with random intercept and slope. Would my reduced model with the assumption of "compound symmetry" meet this criteria?

Comment: Yes. RM-ANOVA corresponds to compound symmetry.

Comment: Well, actually not quite - I think RM-ANOVA with three factors will have more random terms, see here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117660. Smth like `(1|subject) + (1|a:subject) + (1|b:subject) + (1|c:subject) +            (1|a:b:subject) + (1|a:c:subject) + (1|b:c:subject) + (1|a:b:c:subject)`... It's tricky to reproduce this kind of anova with lmer exactly, it might be easier to adopt the mixed model style of thinking ant put w1/w2/w3 to the left of the vertical bar.

Comment: Thank you again very much for your help. Now I think there is no other way for me than leaving the restricted ANOVA based thinking behind and form a real understanding of mixed models.